# iOS - How to get Facebook Campaign information when is installed from Ad

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, ads

We are running an install campaign on Facebook and, when user installs the app due to tapping on an Ad, I would like to fetch the campaign information from within iOS app and send  to our server; like that, we can associate that data to a user in our database and see the lifetime value of campaigns (we offer subscriptions). What I'm looking for is something similar to what we can do when running Search Ads, where we can fetch attribution details via `ADClient.shared().requestAttributionDetails`.

Looking at Facebook docs, I can't find anything pointing me in the right direction. Is there a Facebook iOS SDK api I'm missing?